# Diagonal constraint on product of matrices

Tags: matrices, optimization, non-convex-optimization

I am trying to solve the below optimization problem

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{{A}, {B}, {\Lambda}}{\text{minimize }}
& &
  \|X - AB\Lambda B^TA^T\|_F^2 \\
& \text{subject to}
& & \Lambda~\text{and}~B\Lambda~B^T\text{are diagonal matrices}\\
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
where $X \in R^{n\times n}, A\in R^{n\times k_1}, B \in R^{k_1\times k_2}, \Lambda \in R^{k_2\times k_2}$, $X$ is known and $n > k_1 > k_2$. I am not sure how to put a constraint on $B$ and $\Lambda$ such that $B\Lambda B^T$ is a diagonal matrix. I know I can solve for all unknown using alternative minimization but I am not sure how to include the constraint.

Edit 1: Changed the optimization problem

Comment: You could add another variable $D$, which is required to be diagonal and $B\Lambda B^T=D$

Comment: Are you sure that your formulation is correct? With the current formulation, the solution is trivial: the minimiser is just $(A,B,\Lambda)=(X,I,I)$ and the objective function value is $0$.

Comment: @daw Is there a way to jointly minimize, i.e. without substitution?

Comment: @user1551 My bad, I wrongly formulated the problem, just changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S=AB\Lambda B^TA^T$ and $H=\frac12(X+X^T)$. Then the rank of $S$ is at most $k_2$ and
\begin{align}
\|X-S\|_F^2
&=\operatorname{tr}\left((X-S)^T(X-S)\right)\\
&=\operatorname{tr}(X^TX)-2\operatorname{tr}(X^TS)+\operatorname{tr}(S^TS)\\
&=\operatorname{tr}(X^TX)-2\operatorname{tr}(HS)+\operatorname{tr}(S^TS)\\
&=\operatorname{tr}(X^TX)-\operatorname{tr}(H^TH)+\|H-S\|_F^2.
\end{align}
It follows that the global minimiser $S$ is a best rank-$k_2$ approximation of $H$. That is, if $H=QDQ^T$ is an orthogonal diagonalisation where the diagonal entries of $D$ are arranged in the order of decreasing *magnitude*, and we partition $Q$ and $D$ as $\pmatrix{Q_1&Q_2}$ and $D_1\oplus D_2$, where both $Q_1$ and $D_1$ have $k_2$ columns each, then $S=Q_1D_1Q_1^T$ is a global minimiser. You may now pick any $A,B,\Lambda$ that satisfy your constraints such that $AB\Lambda B^TA^T$ is equal to $S$. E.g. you may simply pick $A=\pmatrix{Q_1&0},\ B=\pmatrix{I_{k_2}\\ 0}$ and $\Lambda=D_1$. The corresponding (minimum possible) objective function value is $\operatorname{tr}(X^TX)-\operatorname{tr}(H^TH)+\sum_{i=1}^{n-k_2}(D_2)_{ii}^2$.

Comment: What if $A$ and $B$ are not square matrices? and how to put a constraint such that $B\Lambda B^T$ is a diagonal matrix?

Comment: @DushyantSahoo See my new edit. By the way, unless you are making corrections, please don't keep changing an answered question. This is considered rude on this site.