# Constraint on product of matrices

Tags: matrices, optimization, non-convex-optimization

I am trying to solve the below optimization problem

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{{A}, {B}, {\Lambda}}{\text{minimize }}
& &
  \|X - AB\Lambda C^TD^T|_F^2 \\
& \text{subject to}
& & \Lambda \text{ and } B\Lambda C^T \text{ are diagonal matrices}\\
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
where $X \in R^{n\times n}, A\in R^{n\times k_1}, D\in R^{n\times k_1}, B \in R^{k_1\times k_2},  C \in R^{k_1\times k_2}, \Lambda \in R^{k_2\times k_2}$, $X$ is known and $n > k_1 > k_2$. I am not sure how to put a constraint on $B$, $C$ and $\Lambda$ such that $B\Lambda C^T$ is a diagonal matrix. I know I can solve for all unknown using alternative minimization but I am not sure how to include the constraint. I have asked a similar question here [Diagonal constraint on product of matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2943181/diagonal-constraint-on-product-of-matrices/2950700?noredirect=1#comment6098299_2950700)

Edit 1: $A, B, C$ and $D$ are sparse matrices i.e. $|B|_1 < \lambda$

Comment: You can choose $\Lambda=I$ without losing any freedom. You then get linear constraints on $B$ from the requirement that $BC^T$ is diagonal. The difficulty is in the product of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @LinAlg Is it possible to get a method completely data-driven? It will be too trivial if I choose $\Lambda = I$, $\Lambda = I$ is one of the solutions but I don't want to make any assumptions about \Lambda$

Comment: How is that too trivial if it leads to the same objective value as a data-dependent $\Lambda$? How should the data affect $\Lambda$?

Comment: The optimization problem is non-convex, so it should have multiple local minima and $\Lambda = I$ might lead to some of the local minima. Are you saying for all the solutions $\Lambda = I$? I think I didn't understand why are you saying that we can choose $\Lambda = I$ without losing any freedom.

Comment: There is always an optimum for which $\Lambda=I$, since you can always rescale the columns of $B$.

Comment: Right, but let's say if I put constraints on $A, B, C$ and $D$ such that they are sparse i.e. $|B|_1 < \lambda$, then how can we solve the problem. In this case, I won't be able to rescale the columns of B.